# Selection from group of objects

Tags: combinatorics

The total number of ways of selecting one or more items from $p$ identical items of one kind, $q$ identical objects of second kind, $r$ identical objects of third kind and n different items is $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)(2^n-1$)

Can someone tell me how this expression  here?I thought number of ways of selection from identical object is always $1$.

Comment: What is $n$?  You have not defined it.

Comment: You have apparently ignored the *or more* part of "*one or more.*"  That being said, your equation is off a bit since you have an unnecessary $2^n-1$ appearing at the end.  You didn't even define $n$ in this problem in the first place.  The number of ways of selecting one or more items from $p$ identical, one or more from $q$ identical, and one or more from $r$ identical is $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)$ and this can be seen by multiplication principle using the steps: "Choose how many copies of the first type of object do you take.  Choose how many from the second type.  Choose how many for the third"

Comment: Having chosen two items of the first type is different than having chosen one item of the first type is further different than having chosen five of the first type etc...

Comment: As an aside, $2^n-1$ is the number of ways to select one or more objects from $n$ *distinct* objects (*which can also be seen by multiplication principle*)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Edited to explain

Comment: @JMoravitz Don't know why but my book has given me that equation .They have further added that each of the "n" distinct objects can be disposed of in two ways either by selecting or rejecting it.

Comment: Then you have either read the question incorrectly, copied the question incorrectly, or the book has an error.  An answer of $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)2^n-1$ would be an answer to the question of if you have $p$ identical items of a first type, $q$ identical of a second type, $r$ identical of a third type, and $n$ additional items all of which are distinct where you want to select items and must pick at least one of each of the first, second, and third types and may pick any number of the distinct items however you are not allowed to pick all of everything.

Comment: An answer of $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)(2^n-1)$ would be for if you need to pick at least one of the first type of ojbect, at least one of the second type, at least one of the third, and at least one of the distinct objects.  No interpretation of the problem as you have originally written it makes sense to have the $2^n-1$ at the end since $n$ is not involved at all in the question.

Comment: @JMoravitzDouble checked this and yeah you are right.I missed the part in the end in a hurry.

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you explain me the identical object part of this equation......

Comment: Take a smaller example.  I have three identical apples and four identical bananas (*hereafter labeled as $a$ and $b$*) and I want to make a fruit basket with these such that I include at least one of each type of fruit.  I could do this as $\{a,b\},\{a,a,b\},\{a,b,b\},\{a,a,a,b\},\{a,a,b,b\},\{a,b,b,b\},\dots,\{a,a,a,b,b,b,b\}$.  Hopefully, this should convince you that there is indeed more than one way to accomplish the task.  Now... looking at it a bit closer again, I can see that there is another error either in the wording or the answer...

Comment: ...then we would have $p$ options (*take one item, take two items,...., on up to taking all p of the items*).  $(p+1)$ is the number of options for taking zero or more.  In any event, once you decide how many options there are for each step, by applying [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) you multiply the number of options available for each step to get the total.

Comment: @JMoravitz {1P.0,0},{1P,1Q,0},{1P,1Q,1R},{0,1Q,1R},{0,0,1R},{2P,0,0}.  like this?Is the total number of ways be same as filling this bracket?

Comment: That is the gist, but it would be a painful process to actually list them all out by hand.  The whole point of an introductory combinatorics class is to teach you how to count without needing to use your fingers and toes to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The actual answer is $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)(2^n)-1$ not  $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)(2^n-1)$

**1 For the identical sets of objects**

Number of objects we can pick from the $p$ identical objects of the first kind are-
$0,1,2,3,...,p-1$ or $p$

Which are exactly $(p+1)$ distinct values
The same applies for each of the other sets of identical items.

**2 For the $n$ distinct objects**

There are $2$ ways for each object -

$1$. The object is chosen
$2$. The object is not chosen

$\therefore$ Number of ways =$2^n$

---

Multiplying each case gives us - $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)(2^n)$ ways
Removing the case that no object is chosen gives us the required answer which gives us $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)(2^n)-1$ ways

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have wrong answer with you. Look up for the correct one first.

Now since you say that you have p number of objects which are of same kind. And similarly q are of one type and r of one type and remaining n of different types.

Assume that you wish to choose from p type items then either you choose 0 from them or one or two or three and so on till pth one. Hence now you have p+1 ways of selecting or choosing from p family items.

Draw the same analogy for q and r too.

But since all are done at same time then its a compulsory event which implies that you need all cases altogether thus multiply all of them.

But there remains n different type of elements. And I assume that you now how 2^n has got to link with its selections.

But wait! As you have assumed that you choise 0 from p or 0 from q or 0 from r then it might also happen that during a particular selection you chose neither of all three. And we are not interested in this case. Hence we subtract 1 at the 'end'